# While Running provider hosted app solution from visual studio in Page_PreInit method getting ' System.TypeInitializationException' Exception

Tags: sharepoint-addin

Am getting 'System.TypeInitializationException' exception in preinit method while running provider hosted app on premise solution from visual studio 2013.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

`TypeInitializationException` is thrown when a static constructor throws an exception or when you try to access a class where the static constructor threw an exception.

Look into it's `InnerException` property as that holds the details on the actual exception that is thrown.

Comment: Getting exception in TokenHelper.GetS2SClientContextwithWindowsIdenitty(hostweb, request.logonidentity)

Comment: @user41938 That usually means something went wrong with the handshake between the site and the app. The solution depends on what type of authentication you use (windows, adfs, fba etc.)

Comment: Am usin windows authetication

Comment: App is deployed to Host web when am clicking the app it needs to redirect to remote web during that time am getting this exception

Comment: My remote web is in Sharepoint-80 site and host web is in different port. In IIs If i try to browse default.aspx page am getting the same exception without running the solution in VS

Comment: Please post a new question with these details.